# How to add a Row at Runtime to Devexpress Gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using devexpress's gridview-control for showing information about files.
You have to select a folder, and then the gridview is going to show the information, like this: name|date|size
but I can't get it done to add a new row to the gridview.
The name of it is gdFiles for example, but what would the command for adding a new line be? Something like gdFiles.insert(x,y,z)?

Comment: Did you check the DevExpress Demo Applications? (Come with source code)

Comment: The ones I saw only got their data directly from a database

Comment: I found that:(myGridcontrol.MainView as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView).AddNewRow(); but it doesn't really work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use methods of your data source to add, delete and modify individual rows if the data source supports these methods:

```
BindingList<Person> personsList = new BindingList<Person>();
gridControl.DataSource = personsList;
//...
personsList.Add(new Person("John", "Smith")); // !!!
```

Or you can use the [ColumnView.AddNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic) method to add a new row to a Grid View. For rows added using the `ColumnView.AddNewRow` method, you can write cell initialization code within a [ColumnView.InitNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_InitNewRowtopic) event handler.

Refer to the [Adding and Deleting Records](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752) topic for more details on adding and deleting records via code.

Please also take a look at [New Item Row Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument778) (this topic describes the new item row - a row that allows end-users to add new records.)

Comment: thanks, that worked. I chose a 4-dimensional arraylist as datasource